# What's p2sh in decodescript RPC method ouput?

Tags: p2sh, json-rpc

Every time i call decodescript method with any input it returns p2sh

```
bitcoin-cli decodescript 1234
{
    "asm" : "[error]",
    "type" : "nonstandard",
    "p2sh" : "2NBbRKQ1VhLw8xeL82ynK4VUUJs9z2pj7Ca"
}
```

i know that p2sh is pay to script hash address, but address of what ? the given script ?

Answer (score 1):

It is the address you would have to give to someone in order for them to pay to that script.